# How to use a file as a graph adjacency list runtime store

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-databases, adjacency-list

I have an in-memory bidirectional graph implemented as adjacency list like so:

```
class MemGraph
{
    struct Node { int id; std::vector<int> from, to; }; //stores ids of adjacent edges
    struct Edge { int id, from, fromIndex, to, toIndex; }; //from, to are ids of nodes and the fromIndex and toIndex are locations in those
    //Index is open-addressing hash table using Node::id and Edge::id as key
    struct Index { int count; std::vector<int> data; };

    std::vector<Node> nodes;
    Index nodeIndex;
    std::vector<Edge> edges;
    Index edgeIndex;
};
```

This allows for `O(1)` ammortized for all operations (insert, remove, search and random access by both id and index position). Inserts are merely appends in the respective lists. Removals are done using "swap with last" technique (requires some minor but always constant updating of the swapped element).

Is there a way to use this approach (or modified version) with files (instead of vectors) as backend while maintaining `O(1)` complexity?

The problem I ran into are the vectors of adjacent edges. Whenever I modify them the whole node needs to be re-inserted into the file at the end. The same applies to edges but those are always constant size whereas the nodes can be huge (and thus violates the requirement of `O(1)` time complexity).

Comment: I assume the reason you need to move the nodes to the end is because the length of the adjacency vectors changes?
You can use the same technique by which std::vector makes appending ammortized O(1): having a buffer and doubling it's size if exceeded.

Comment: @wonce Yes the assumption is correct. I guess removals would be easier but appending would be a problem. The buffer idea is a good one though although I foresee quite a bit of overhead in it but then again the disk space is relatively cheap so I will give it a try.